# Python: Trouble converting list of dictionary data into a dictionary so i can use key, value functions

Tags: python

```
[{'DBNOs': 2,
  'assists': 0,
  'boosts': 0,
  'damageDealt': 129.820038,
  'deathType': 'byplayer',
  'headshotKills': 0,
  'heals': 0,
  'killPlace': 35,
  'killPoints': 1295,
  'killPointsDelta': 3.15819788,
  'killStreaks': 0,
  'kills': 1,
  'lastKillPoints': 0,
  'lastWinPoints': 0,
  'longestKill': 3,
  'mostDamage': 0,
  'name': 'Esskedit',
  'playerId': 'account.7a54835609584b9c943b213345ea7ffb',
  'revives': 1,
  'rideDistance': 2023.24707,
  'roadKills': 0,
  'teamKills': 1,
  'timeSurvived': 655,
  'vehicleDestroys': 0,
  'walkDistance': 1113.72375,
  'weaponsAcquired': 0,
  'winPlace': 17,
  'winPoints': 1281,
  'winPointsDelta': -6.71400356},
 {'rank': 6, 'teamId': 9},
 {'rank': 10, 'teamId': 1},
 {'rank': 13, 'teamId': 28}]
```

This is just a portion of the list, i want to convert the [] into {}.

A second problem is at the end of the data. there are random dictionaries containing 'rank' and 'teamID, that i would like to NOT include inside my new dict.

I hope this clears up some of the questions that you may have.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is the desired output for this case? What key do you want to use for each element of the list?

Comment: You already have a dictionary which is inside an array. I don't really understand what's you want...

Comment: Hi Ali,

so right now there is a list holding this data (you can see the [] enclosing the data)

Is there a way i can convert the [] into a dictionary? but maintain the data inside.

once i am able to convert the list into a dictionary, then i can do search functions using keys and values. 

Hope this clears things up! Thank you for asking

Comment: The only thing in the list is a dictionary. So suppose your current list is called `myList`, you could just get the dictionary with `myDictionary = myList[0]`

Comment: You'll have to give an example of that your expected result is. Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume your list is called items.

```
new_dict = {}
for i in items:
    for k, v in i.items():
        new_dict[k] = v
```

This takes the 1 value from your list, that dict, and adds each key and value to a new dict. You can then retrieve keys/values from the new_dict variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i was hoping for.

I ran this code, but it was only able to store 1 dictionary. Do you perhaps know why? there are 29 dictionaries holding similar data

Comment: @Raegis You want 29 new dictionaries to get created? Do the dictionaries have the same keys?

Comment: I am sorry if i am unclear since i am a beginner.

I have 29 dictionaries stored inside a list. very similar to the dictionary i showed above.

I want to store all 29 of these dictionaries inside 1 dictionary.

The method you showed me above worked, but it only stored 1 of the 29 dictionaries inside the new_dict

Comment: @Raegis A dict in python cannot have 2 of the same key. I'm wondering if all 29 of your dicts have identical keys and so each loop through is overwriting the previous values. Do each of your dicts have identical keys and different values?

Comment: I see. 

Yes, each of my dictionaries have the identical keys and different values.

There is also another issues. Inside this list there are also random dictionaries which are different from the dictionary i mentioned above.... i'm relatively new in handling json and i don't know how to remove them.

e.g. : {'rank': 15, 'teamId': 2} 

I don't have use for these, but i am unsure of how to remove them.

Comment: i edited the question to show you the random dictionaries inside the data. Other than a few of those random ones, the rest of the dictionaries should look like the first set of data.

Answer (score 0):

my expected results is for it to look like this

```
  {
 {'DBNOs': 2,
  'assists': 0,
  'boosts': 0,
  'damageDealt': 129.820038,
  'deathType': 'byplayer',
  'headshotKills': 0,
  'heals': 0,
  'killPlace': 35,
  'killPoints': 1295,
  'killPointsDelta': 3.15819788,
  'killStreaks': 0,
  'kills': 1,
  'lastKillPoints': 0,
  'lastWinPoints': 0,
  'longestKill': 3,
  'mostDamage': 0,
  'name': 'Esskedit',
  'playerId': 'account.7a54835609584b9c943b213345ea7ffb',
  'revives': 1,
  'rideDistance': 2023.24707,
  'roadKills': 0,
  'teamKills': 1,
  'timeSurvived': 655,
  'vehicleDestroys': 0,
  'walkDistance': 1113.72375,
  'weaponsAcquired': 0,
  'winPlace': 17,
  'winPoints': 1281,
  'winPointsDelta': -6.71400356},
}
```

Comment: @jbch this is how it should look like. Thank you for looking at my problem